# Does the order matter when overriding the == operator?

Tags: c#

In C# I can override `==` with my own implementation. For example:

```
public static bool operator ==(SomeType x, SomeOtherType y)
{
    return false;
}
```

Does the order of parameters matter here? Does it make a difference to swap `SomeType` with `SomeOtherType`?

Comment: Yes, the order is important (for the operator resolution) when the types are different, see details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691327(v=vs.71).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691326(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does. In your case,

```
SomeType x;
SomeOtherType y;
bool b = x == y;
```

would call your function, but

```
bool b = y == x;
```

would *not*.

Overloaded operator functions in this respect have the same behaviour as any regular function with more than one parameter type: the passed parameters must match the expected types with the *order* clearly mattering too.